# D3 - Load in and display data, row by row with set delay

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use time series data to plot bubbles on a map. What I would like to do is slowly plot these bubbles based on their date rather than all at once.

Something similar to: 
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/mapping-the-spread-of-drought-across-the-us.html?_r=0

Here is some sample data:

date    count  code,country,lat,lon,counter
1/28/16  3     AND,Andorra,42.5,1.516667,0.577121255
1/29/16,146,ARE,United Arab Emirates,24.46666667,54.366667,2.264352856
1/30/16,13,AFG,Afghanistan,34.51666667,69.183333,1.213943352

[Example of D3 Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz1ZC.png)

I have already looked at MB's tutorials on Path Transitions, Udacity's course on D3, and many questions on Stack Overflow.

I have previously tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` but most of the examples were with multiple data files. I would like to use one datafile line by line.

Code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0, 5 ])
    .scale(200)
    .rotate([-180,0]);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.count + "</span>"+ "<br/>" + d.country;

  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the World
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {

svg.call(tip)

// load and display the cities
d3.csv("cities2_or.csv", function(error, data) {

    max = d3.max(data, function(d) 
        {return +d.counter})
    coloring = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max])
        .range(["blue", "green"])
    radiusing = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max])
        //.domain([0, 100])
        .range([2, 30])

    g.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")

       .on('mouseover', tip.show)
       .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

       .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
       })
       .style("r", function(d){
                return radiusing(+d.counter)
                ;})
       //.style("opacity", .5)
       .style("fill", function(d){
                return coloring(+d.counter);
                }) 
    });
```

Thanks for any help

I took @adilapapaya suggestions and tried using the delay function but I am only able to plot the first point.
Instead of the `g.selectAll` that I was using above I have replaced it with the following. This however only plots the first point in my csv file and then stops.

```
g.append("circle")
    .data(data)
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
   })
    .style("r", 20)
    .transition()
    .duration(1)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i*1; })
    .style("r",30)
    .style("fill","green");
```

Comment: Look into d3's `transition`, in particular, [`transition.delay`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay). You can set the opacity to 1 only after a time-interval that's specific to a given point (e.g. `i*50` where `i` is the index). Let me know if you want me to write up a more complete example...

Comment: Well I got very close and this is close to what I am looking for. However, I will load the first point, but then not any of the others. @adilapapaya

Comment: Have a look at this minimal working example - https://jsfiddle.net/ds0exs5r/5/

Not sure where you're going wrong, but perhaps you could set up a jsfiddle to show us? There are a few missing semicolons in your original code, not sure if there may be other errors too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew Guy who helped find the JS fiddle example for me. Worked perfectly. My issue was not using the `enter` before hand. Here is the final code. Please respond if anyone has any questions.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0, 5 ])
    .scale(200)
    .rotate([-180,0]);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.count + "</span>"+ "<br/>" + d.country;

  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the World
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {

svg.call(tip)

// load and display the cities
d3.csv("cities2_or.csv", function(error, data) {

    max = d3.max(data, function(d) 
        {return +d.counter})
    coloring = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max])
        .range(["blue", "green"])
    radiusing = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max])
        //.domain([0, 100])
        .range([2, 30])

    g.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .on('mouseover', tip.show)
       .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
       })
//        .style("r", function(d){
//                  return radiusing(+d.counter)
//                  ;})
       //.style("opacity", .5)
       .style("fill", function(d){
                return coloring(+d.counter);})
       .style("r",0)
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i*200; })
      .style("r",30);



});


g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});

// zoom and pan
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        g.selectAll("path")  
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 

  });

svg.call(zoom)
```